# which of the following is correct to use?

Tags: grammar

I'm confused about which one to use. Is it the first or second?

Let's see exactly how this process is working.
or
let's see how this process is working exactly.

Comment: The first is correct - _exactly_ modifies _how_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let's **see exactly** how this process is working.

Here **exactly** modifies **see**, and the sentence stresses the *manner in which you see* the working of the process. (**Case of an Adverb modifying a Verb**).

> Let's see how this process is working exactly.

Here **exactly** modifies **how this process is working**, and the *stress* shifts from **see** to **how this is working**. In other words, you are interested in knowing the **manner** in which the process is working. (**Case of an Adverb modifying an Adverb Phrase**).

The second version above could also be rephrased as—

> Let's see how exactly the process is working.

Here *exactly* modifies *how* (**Case of an Adverb modifying another Adverb**).